# Q: Efficient Kubernetes load balancing

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress

I've been looking into Kubernetes networking, more specifically, how to serve HTTPS users the most efficient.

I was watching this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Omvgd7Hg1I and from 22:18 he explains what the problem is with a load balancer that is not pod aware. Now, how they solve this in kubernetes is by letting the nodes also act as a 'router' and letting the node pass the request on to another node. (explained at 22:46). This does not seem very efficient, but when looking around SoundCloud (https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/how-soundcloud-uses-haproxy-with-kubernetes-for-user-facing-traffic) actually seems to do something similar to this but with NodePorts. They say that the overhead costs less than creating a better load balancer.

From what I have read an option might be using an ingress controller. Making sure that there is not more than one ingress controller per node, and routing the traffic to the specific nodes that have an ingress controller. That way there will not be any traffic re-routing needed. However, this does add another layer of routing.

This information is all from 2017, so my question is: is there any pod aware load balancer out there, or is there some other method that does not involve sending the http request and response over the network twice?

Thank you in advance,
Hendrik

**EDIT:**

A bit more information about my use case:

There is a bare-metal setup with kubernetes. The firewall load balances the incomming data between two HAProxy instances. These HAProxy instances do ssl termination and forward the traffic to a few sites. This includes an exchange setup, a few internal IIS sites and a nginx server for a static web app. The idea is to transform the app servers into kubernetes.

Now my main problem is how to get the requests from HAProxy into kubernetes. I see a few options:

1. Use the SoundCloud setup. The infrastructure could stay almost the same, the HAProxy server can still operate the way they do now.
2. I could use an ingress controller on EACH node in the kubernetes cluster and have the firewall load balance between the nodes. I believe it is possible to forward traffic from the ingress controller to server outside the cluster, e.g. exchange.
3. Some magic load balancer that I do not know about that is pod aware and able to operate outside of the kubernetes cluster.

Option 1 and 2 are relatively simple and quite close in how they work, but they do come with a performance penalty. This is the case when the node that the requests gets forwarded to by the firewall does not have the required pod running, or if another pod is doing less work. The request will get forwarded to another node, thus, using the network twice.

Is this just the price you pay when using Kubernetes, or is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Could you tell us more about your particular use case ? And what is actually your biggest concern about using **loadbalancer** which is not `Pod` aware ? In most cases the load distribution will be fairly close-to-equal even when using `externalTrafficPolicy: Local`, which is currently used instead of annotation, which was discussed in the presentation.

Comment: @mario I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

How traffic heads to pods depend on whether a managed cluster is used.

Almost all cloud providers can forward traffic in a cloud-native way in their managed K8s clusters. First, you can a managed cluster with some special network settings (e.g. vpc-native cluster of GKE). Then, the only thing you need to do is to create a `LoadBalancer` typed Service to expose your workload. You can also create Ingresses for your L7 workloads, they are going to be handled by provided IngressControllers (e.g. ALB of AWS).

In an on-premise cluster without any cloud provider(OpenStack or vSphere),  the only way to expose workloads is `NodePort` typed Service. It doesn't mean you can't improve it.

If your cluster is behind reverse proxies (the SoundCloud case), setting `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` to Services could break traffic forwarding among work nodes. When traffic received through NodePorts, they are forwarded to local Pods or dropped if Pods reside on other nodes. Reserve proxy will mark these NodePort as unhealthy in the backend health check and reject to forward traffic to them. Another choice is to use `topology-aware service routing`. In this case, local Pods have priorities and traffic is still forwarded between node when no local Pods matched.

For IngressController in on-prem clusters, it is a little different. You may have some work nodes that have EIP or public IP. To expose HTTP(S) services, an IngressController usually deployed on those work nodes through DaemeaSet and HostNetwork such that clients access the IngressController via the **well-known** ports and EIP of nodes. These work nodes regularly don't accept other workloads (e.g. infra node in OpenShift) and one more forward on the Pod network is needed. You can also deploy the IngressController on all work nodes as well as other workloads, so traffic could be forwarded to a closer Pod if the IngressController supports `topology-aware service routing` although it can now.

Hope it helps!